# set axes ticks on double log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a double logarithmic plot with matplotlib, I would like to have axes ticks at given points, and with "standard" label (no scientific notation).

This code does not produce the desired output

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.errorbar(x = [1, 2, 4, 8, 10],
             y = [1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 ],
             yerr = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05],
             fmt='o', capsize=2)
axes=plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([1, 10])
axes.set_ylim([10**(-2),2])
axes.set_xscale('log')
axes.set_yscale('log')
axes.set_xticks([1,5,10])
plt.show()
```

What I get is

[image: plot]

I would like to have removed the x labels, and only have "1, 5, 10".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plot above, the mid-point ticks are minor ticks, while the last one is major. So, to change it, you can replace the below code...

```
axes.set_xticks([1,5,10])
```

with...

```
def format_fn(tick_val, tick_pos):
    if tick_val in [1,5,10]:
        return int(tick_val)
    else:
        return ''
    
axes.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(format_fn)
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(format_fn)
```

..which will give you this plot.

[image]